# Rx.Net Operator that ignores some values until they are identical during a certain amount of time

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to create a Rx.Net operator that will have the following behavior:

- When an event is of "normal kind", return that event directly
- When an event is of "special kind", wait that you have received repeated events of that kind during a certain amount of time

I would like to have something like the following marble.

When the message type is A or B, we send it through directly. When the message is C, we want to make sure that it's not just a transitive state and only send it if it was like that for a certain amount of time. This is measured by the time between the first `C` and the current `C` that we receive. After that specific amount of time, all `C` is "accepted" and we pass them through as normal ones.

[image: Marble diagram with non ignored]

Here's what it looks when we have received `C` that was just transitive and we want to ignore it.

[image: Marbe diagram with ignored]

I've tried to do something with the `Scan` operator, playing with returning the previous/current values when I have a specific value, but it feels really hacky.

Here's some code that I wrote for a demonstration of what I tried. In that case, the "special kind" is just when the value is 999, but in the operator, I'd like to do it could be another test or even a function passed to my operator.

```cs
var oneObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => 999);
var intObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(value => (int)value);

var myObservable = intObservable.Take(4).Concat(oneObservable.Take(3)).Timestamp().Repeat();

var test = myObservable.Scan(
    (previous: default(Timestamped<int>), current: default(Timestamped<int>)),
    (accumulated, current) =>
    {
        if (current.Value == 999)
        {
            if (accumulated.previous.Value != 999)
            {
                return (accumulated.current, current);
            }
            
            return (accumulated.previous, current);
        }
        else if(accumulated.current.Value == 999){
            return (accumulated.previous, current);
        }

        return (accumulated.current, current);
    })
    .Where(
        value => value.current.Value != 999 
        || (value.previous.Value == 999 && value.current.Timestamp - value.previous.Timestamp > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)))
    .Select(value => value.current);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of a custom `IgnoreNonEstablishedContiguousValue` operator, with the desirable functionality:

```
/// <summary>
/// Ignores elements having a specific value, until this value has
/// been repeated contiguously for a specific duration.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<T> IgnoreNonEstablishedContiguousValue<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    T value,
    TimeSpan dueTimeUntilEstablished,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default,
    IScheduler scheduler = default)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    scheduler ??= Scheduler.Default;
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        IStopwatch stopwatch = null;
        return source.Do(item =>
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(item, value))
                stopwatch ??= scheduler.StartStopwatch();
            else
                stopwatch = null;
        })
        .Where(_ => stopwatch == null || stopwatch.Elapsed >= dueTimeUntilEstablished);
    });
}
```

This implementation is based on the `Do` and `Where` operators. I'm not a big fan of using the `Scan` operator as a building block, because it results in verbose and less readable code IMHO. The purpose of the `Observable.Defer` wrapper is to isolate the state of each subscription.

Usage example:

```
var oneObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(_ => 999);
var intObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Select(v => (int)v);

IObservable<int> myObservable = intObservable.Take(4).Concat(oneObservable.Take(3))
    .Repeat()
    .IgnoreNonEstablishedContiguousValue(999, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

Comment: @Gimly I should point out a minor flaw of this implementation. In case the `TimeSpan` is very small (less than ~30 msec), it becomes theoretically possible for the first special value to be emitted. That might happen if the current thread is suspended by the OS immediately after creating the `stopwatch`. When the thread is later resumed, the `stopwatch.Elapsed` property might be already larger than the specified `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
public static IObservable<T> FilterSpecials<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> specialDetector,
    TimeSpan timeUntilEstablished,
    IScheduler scheduler = default)
{
    return source.FilterSpecials(specialDetector, Observable.Timer(timeUntilEstablished), scheduler);
}

public static IObservable<T> FilterSpecials<T, U>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> specialDetector,
    IObservable<U> observeSpecialsUntilEstablished,
    IScheduler scheduler = default)
{
    scheduler = scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default;

    return source
        .Select(i => (value: i, isSpecial: specialDetector(i)))
        .StartWith((value: default(T), isSpecial: false))
        .Publish(_source => _source
            .Zip(_source.Skip(1))
            .Select((t, index) => (
                newValue: t.Second.value,
                isNewValueSpecial: t.Second.isSpecial,
                isPreviousValueSpecial: t.First.isSpecial,
                isFirstElement: index == 0)
            )
            .SelectMany((t, index) => t.isNewValueSpecial
                ? (t.isFirstElement || !t.isPreviousValueSpecial)       
                    ? _source.SkipUntil(observeSpecialsUntilEstablished).TakeWhile(i => i.isSpecial).Select(i => i.value)   
                    : Observable.Empty<T>()
                : Observable.Return(t.newValue)
        ));
}
```

At core, the issue is that for the first special value, you want to temporarily stop listening to your regular `source` observable, and switch to something that looks like this:

```
source.SkipUntil(observeSpecialsUntilEstablished).TakeWhile(i => i.isSpecial).Select(i => i.value)
```

When you have that special observable listening, you can ignore your regular one and emit `Observable.Empty<T>()`. When you don't have special values, you're effectively doing `source.SelectMany(i => Observable.Return(i))`, which is a no-op to return `source`.

Everything else is window-dressing: The `Zip`, `Publish` and `StartWith` are there to make it easy to compare to previous value. That could be abstracted away if you want. Putting everything in that named tuple is done to help with self-documentation and to prevent re-calling the `specialDetector` in case it's an expensive operation.

Comment: Interesting approach. This implementation assumes that the `observeSpecialsUntilEstablished` parameter is a cold sequence, that restarts every time it's subscribed. A safer approach would be to replace it with a `Func<IObservable<U>>` parameter, and create a new sequence each time the `SkipUntil` is called.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your very complete and interesting approaches. Both fit my needs, I decided to accept @TheodorZoulias' answer because I find it a bit more succinct and easier to understand.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, it doesn't have to be a cold sequence. It can be a hot one as well. Though cold would be the common scenario.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The scenarios where `Func<IObservable<U>` is more useful than `IObservable<U>` are pretty far and few between. The API routinely uses Observable parameters as sentinels like I have, without providing `Func<IObservable>` overloads.

Comment: I have in mind the [`Window`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/118476bec440f5ae2a916f8ca2010422a9935c5a/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable.Multiple.cs#L923) operator, which has an overload that accepts a `Func<TWindowOpening, IObservable<TWindowClosing>> windowClosingSelector` parameter. Whether this specific case requires a similar treatment depends on the usage scenarios of the `FilterSpecials<T, U>` operator. Passing an `Observable.Timer` works because this sequence happens to be cold by design. It wouldn't produce the desirable behavior if it was hot.

Comment: I guess the philosophical question is: In case an operator accepts a secondary `IObservable<U>` argument, is it allowed to subscribe more than once to this auxiliary sequence, during a single subscription to the resulting `IObservable<T>` sequence?